# Wald Chi-Squared Test between two variable in one mixed effect model in r

Tags: r, mixed-models, nlme, longitudinal

I tried to finish a homework in longitudinal data analysis. 
the question is to compare the difference in the cross-sectional and longitudinal effects of age (baseline cross-sectional:baseage, longtitudinal age: agechange) within a model.

the model I code like:
fit<-lme(logfev1~baseage+agechange+height,random = ~1|id,correlation=corAR1(form=~visit|id),logfev1)

In Stata we just need to code like : test baseage=agechange, then the answer will shows:
 test baseage = change_age

```
[logfev1]baseage - [logfev1]change_age = 0

       chi2(  1) =    0.41
     Prob > chi2 =    0.5244
```

but in R I really don't know how to do the test (wald test).

Comment: If you need the dataset I could send to you, I don't know how to attach a dataset here. thx

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are trying to program here, so maybe your question better belong on [stats.se] where questions about statistical test are on-topic. Otherwise you really should be very clear on what you mean by "the wald test" and describe what stats you need to calculate that value. Provide the relevant documentation from Stata if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `glmer` instead of the `lme` method you can use `summary(fit)` and it will actually give you the Wald Test as a part of its output.

Or you can call the `Anova(fit)` from the car package on your lme and it will return a Wald's Chi Square result.

You can type `?glmer` in the console of rStudio to read about it and if you install the car package and load it you can run ?Anova (captalized) to get the low down on the method there